# keeping the socket connection open in spring integration

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, spring-integration

Spring integration has a way to keep the socket connection open by setting single-use="false". My client wants to keep the connection open and send multiple transactions on the same connection.

Here is the configuration that I plan to use:

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="crLfServer"
        type="server"
        port="${availableServerSocket}"
        single-use="false"
        so-timeout="10000"
        using-nio="false" 
        serializer="connectionSerializeDeserialize"
        deserializer="connectionSerializeDeserialize"
        />

    <bean id="connectionSerializeDeserialize" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayStxEtxSerializer"/>
```

If I make single-use="false", is the connection open as long the client keep the connection open?

If the client does not send data between the requests (for example second transaction is sent after 30 minutes), is the connection going to be closed in the server because there is no traffic after first request?

is there any configuration to be set to keep the connection open for long time?

Please help.

To Summarize, the following configuration works to read data:

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="crLfServer"
        type="server"
        port="${availableServerSocket}"
        single-use="false"
        so-timeout="0"
        using-nio="false" 
        serializer="connectionSerializeDeserialize"
        deserializer="connectionSerializeDeserialize"
        />
```

Comment: I wonder what makes you to think different way... Are you observing any problems? Maybe your `so-timeout="10000"` isn't enough? By default it is `-1` - infinite

Comment: You are correct Artem. I have to set so-timeout="0" so that server reads on the existing connection. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: That is generally not a recommended setting, unless you absolutely trust your client(s) - if a badly behaved client doesn't close the socket you might eventually run out of resources.

Comment: Thats correct Gary. In my case, I know there are only 5 clients that will be configured to use this and the server is running just to support them. All others will be sent a server with single-use="true".